# One word for call for a quick unplanned meeting

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I am trying to finding one word that describes as "asking to meet for a quick & short meeting in a short notice"( where meeting is unplanned)"

The word should be polite as I want to use among people which include high designated people like CEO, Investor & so on.

Just FYI - Meeting would be online
Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use one word.  I'd say:  The problem with X can't wait.  We need to discuss yesterday.

Comment: Every ques­tion should de­scribe the asker’s prior ef­forts to find an an­swer, and ex­plain why the re­sults were not ad­e­quate to an­swer the ques­tion. Some re­search is re­quired on ev­ery ques­tion. This is called our re­search re­quire­ment. Re­search can take many forms: check­ing ref­er­ences such as an on­line English dic­tio­nary, the­saurus, or gram­mar, search­ing this site for sim­i­lar ques­tions, search­ing the web, or putting sub­stan­tial thought into the ques­tion on your own. Please **[ᴇᴅɪᴛ]** your ques­tion and de­tail your re­search re­sults.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple things going on, which pretty much make it impossible to come up with a *single* word.

For quick, I might use [**brief**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brief). For unplanned, I might use [**impromptu**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impromptu).

I can't think of a noun for meetings of either of those types—or of an adjective that means *quick and unplanned*.

So, in a business setting, I would ask:

> Do you have time for a brief impromptu meeting?